# Generating Scala Play project for IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I am new to Play Framework. I wished to make a simple hello world project using SBT (without activator), but unless I did something wrong it seems to me that not all of the files and folders are generated.

Followed the instructions here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/IDE

Can anyone direct me to some resource that could help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you specify the exact problem you are struck at and share your project structure/directory layout ?

Comment: my directory structure doesn't contain the app folder, conf folder and others... after generating it I have only .idea, .idea-modules, project and target and a file build.sbt.

Answer (score 0):

First, follow "Create a new application without Activator" section here:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.1/NewApplication

Then run "idea" in SBT console to generate .idea and .idea_modules directories with IntelliJ IDEA configuration. Afterwards, use File - Open dialog in the IDE.

The steps above will create an empty application. You will have to create a controller, a view and routes file yourself if you don't want to install activator. Still I advise you to install activator where you'll find plenty of templates including "hello playframework" that would fit your needs.